# robots.txt file Help needed

Tags: seo, robots.txt

What if I put same robots.txt file in multiple directories and folders?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /otherdirname/dirname2/
```

Can it'll affect anyhow ??

And how much time it generally takes to refine the search engine results?

Regards

Comment: See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35506/robots-txt-not-updated

Answer (score 4):

No, robots.txt should be placed in root directory only.

Meaning http://www.example.com/robots.txt

General for search bots there is no rule to ban those directories. There are search bots, that will crawl your robots.txt directories as well.

Answer (score 2):

First: it's useless to put a robots.txt file anywhere else than the website roots. Web crawler ONLY check at this places: http://www.yourwebsite.com/robots.txt

Your example tell to EVERY web crawler (of course, only "legal" one, bad robots don't care) to not index /otherdirname/dirname2/. It's NOT disalowing to crawl /otherdirname.

You might need MANY Disallow command to reflect your needs.

Please see the "official" web site for help: [http://www.robotstxt.org/](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you add robot text, then search engine can't crawl that pages as you disallow those pages.

Comment: The question was about putting the file in several places, not what it does.